# Custom product status get filtered on all product list views

Tags: customization, woocommerce-offtopic, post-status

I registred a new product status with this code :

```
function register_custom_post_status(){
        register_post_status( 'invalid', array(
            'label'                     => __( 'Not valid', 'xx' ),
            'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'not valid <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Not valid <span class="count">(%s)</span>'),
            'public'                    => false,
            'exclude_from_search'       => true,
            'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
            'show_in_admin_status_list' => true
        ));
    }
```

When I set a product on this status ( $product->set_status(‘invalid’); ) the all products list table filter out my product and shows it only in his separate table list. But ‘show_in_admin_all_list’ is set to true, so why happen this? I’m confused.

Answer (score 0):

I think Below code will slove your problem.I have tested it.

`/**
 * Add 'Unread' post status.
 */
function wpdocs_custom_post_status(){
     register_post_status( 'unread', array(
            'label'                     => _x( 'Unread', 'post' ),
            'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Unread (%s)', 'Unread (%s)'),
            'public'                    => true,
            'exclude_from_search'       => false,
            'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
            'show_in_admin_status_list' => true
        ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpdocs_custom_post_status' );
function my_custom_status_add_in_quick_edit() {
    echo "
    jQuery(document).ready( function() {
        jQuery( 'select[name=\"_status\"]' ).append( 'Unread' );

    }); 
    ";
}
add_action('admin_footer-edit.php','my_custom_status_add_in_quick_edit');
function my_custom_status_add_in_post_page() {
    echo "
    jQuery(document).ready( function() {

        jQuery( 'select[name=\"post_status\"]' ).append( 'Unread' );
    });
    ";
}
add_action('admin_footer-post.php', 'my_custom_status_add_in_post_page');
add_action('admin_footer-post-new.php', 'my_custom_status_add_in_post_page');`